# How to use Deployment agent with TFS 2015 (update 3)?

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild, ms-release-management

I wonder is there possibility to use Microsoft deployment agents with TFS 2015 (update 3) release management?

The situation is that client doesn't provides any access to her network (except VPN connection). In that case I can't use WinRM to deploy our web site to client's servers. I wonder maybe i could use deployment agents for that?

Maybe someone can provide good example how to configure TFS 2015 (update 3) release management to deploy website over deployment agent? Everything what I could find was related with TFS 2015 (until update 2), but as you know release management has changed after TFS 2015 update 2.

Answer (score 0):

Release Management features have been integrated into Team Foundation Server 2015 Update 2 and above, and into the **Release** hub in TFS web access.

The newer web-based version is the recommended alternative to the server and client version of Release Management. If you do not already have Release Management installed, we encourage you to use the web-based version in TFS 2015 Update 2 and above. If you are already using an earlier server and client version of Release Management, you should be aware that no new features will be added to these versions.

> If you insist on using the server and client version of Release
>   Management, start from [this article](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/release/previous-version/release-management-overview), and more information of
>   releasing your app to environments with deployment agents, check the
>   following article:
>
> https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/release/previous-version/release-with-agents
>
> If you would like to use newer web-based version of Release
>   Management, you can start from [this article](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/release/getting-started/understand-rm), and get more
>   information of new Release Management from the following article:
>
> https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/release/overview